# HTTP to HTTPS - Too many redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a site with Wordpress. I need some single page to redirect HTTPS

I get code form stackoverflow and put in .htaccess

```
        # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /online-order-auto [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/online-order-auto [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com\.swtest\.ru$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The browser wrote "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".
I cant understand whats a problem

Comment: this code redirects http to https and https to http, so you have endless loop

Comment: What is `^(www\.)?site\.com\.swtest\.ru$` supposed to be? You certainly don't want to make the `www` optional in the canonical redirect, that will create a redirect loop. (Although the host is mashed in its current state, so will never match.) This is also after all your WP stuff, so will never be seen anyway.

Comment: I delete it, but redirects still here. I need redirect to https only in /online-order-auto/ When i click any link in this page i need to return http

Comment: @user2896218 note that it's insecure to only redirect some urls to https. The only protection against man-in-the-middle is https on the full website + HSTS

Comment: "I delete it, but redirects still here." - make sure you've cleared your browser cache. 301 redirects will be cached by the browser.

Comment: I cleared browser cache (Chrome, clear cache and hardware refresh). I know, that it is not secure and good. Unfortunatly, my client  want like this (CTR, seo, etc). Please, help me.I checked all strings. But browser told me - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. The error happened in theese strings - RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /onlajn-zakaz-avto/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? The negated condition should prevent the redirect loop. What URL are you requesting? Do you get the rewrite loop regardless of the URL requested?

Answer (score 4):

Try this. I've been looking all over and this is the only way I could make it work...

```
#non-www. http to www. https
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#non-www. https to www. https
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yup this did it for me. I've tried literally over a dozen codes for .htaccess + going through the wp-config file, none worked. This fixed it for me and now I've got 301's for http www & non-www directing properly to https. I have no idea why this small change worked but this is definitely the best solution I've found